# Programatically grab entire web pages using PHP and PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, php, phantomjs

I'm a PHP newbie. I want to capture the browser output of some web pages in PHP for further manipulation. I am calling PhantomJS to capture my JS pages. However my results are unpredictable. Sometimes I get the page I want at other times I don't.

How can I get consistent results all the time? I have tried adding a timeout to ensure my pages fully load, but this does'nt work. What am I doing wrong?

My PHP code follows:

```
$linksArray = array("https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/biz.clarinet.sample/Jku67hVW5KI", "https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/biz.clarinet.sample/JezUT-5wDso", "https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/biz.clarinet.sample/e4_XYi3ZrUQ");
$count = 1;

foreach($linksArray as $val) {    
    $buffer = '';
$output = array();
exec("phantomjs C:\Users\Desktop\demo.js ".$val, $output);

$fp = fopen($count.".html", "w");
foreach ($output as $line){
    $tmp = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $line);
    $buffer .= $tmp;
}
unset($output);
fwrite($fp, $buffer);
fclose($fp);
$count++;
}
```

My demo.js code is:

```
var system = require('system');
var page = require('webpage').create();
var address;

address = system.args[1];

page.open(address, function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to load the address!');
        phantom.exit();
    } else {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            console.log(page.content);
            phantom.exit();
        }, 2000); 
    }
});
```

Comment: i would try using this https://github.com/jonnnnyw/php-phantomjs

Comment: @DominikGoltermann: Looks interesting. I've tried to run the first example but it does'nt work. Is there a working example?

Comment: @DominikGoltermann: Got it to run, no change, I still get a blank page.

Comment: there is an example on their github site. haven't tried it myself though.